# Using x.isdigit() for floats?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, aggregation

I want my code to compute the sum of the values in the numeric column X per value of column Y

```
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        csv_l=list(reader)
        
rows = len(csv_l)-1
columns = len(csv_l[0]) 
without_header = csv_l[1:]   
        
number_list = [[int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in lst] for lst in without_header]
my_dict = {}

for d in number_list:
    if d[0] in my_dict.keys():
        my_dict[d[0]] += d[3]
    else:
        my_dict[d[0]] = d[3]
```

If the value in the input CSV column is an integer, it works perfectly fine but I have found that if the value is a float, isdigit() fails and it returns the result as the floats pieced together as strings instead of an addition.

I used pandas for this and here it works, but I would want it in "pure python".

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(filePath)
new_dataframe = dataframe.groupby('Column Y')['Column X'].sum().reset_index(name='Sum of Values')
return(new_dataframe)
```

Comment: You mean without using any library?

Comment: `isdigit()` method only exists for strings if I recall correctly. Not sure how you apply it to floats and not have AttributeErrors pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Is this close to what you are trying to achieve?

Setting up the data:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': np.random.choice(list('ABCD'), size=16), 
                   'Y': np.random.random(size=16)})
table = df.values
```

Grouping by `X` column without pandas, iteratively filling a `dict`:

```py
res = {}
for n, v in table:
    if n in res.keys():
        res[n] += v
    else:
        res[n] = v
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something along these lines is what you are looking for?

```py
reader = csv.reader(f)
csv_l=list(reader)
        
rows = len(csv_l)-1
columns = len(csv_l[0]) 
without_header = csv_l[1:]   

def x_to_num(x):
    try:
        x = int(x)
    except Exception:
        pass
    return x
        
number_list = [[x_to_num(x) for x in lst] for lst in without_header]
my_dict = {}

for d in number_list:
    if d[0] in my_dict.keys():
        my_dict[d[0]] += d[3]
    else:
        my_dict[d[0]] = d[3]
```

If `x` is numeric, then it converts `x` to an integer, otherwise, it leaves `x` as is.